# Dashing dashboard won't display on Windows

Tags: ruby, curl, sinatra, dashing

I ran exactly the following:

```
dashing new project
cd project
bundle install && dashing start
```

It listed the "using" output and began the server. [Output here](http://pastebin.com/Bm32rrtm).

Visiting `localhost:3030` resulted in a plain grey web page with nothing on it but the text `Try this: curl -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "text": "Hey, Look what I can do!" }' \http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome` at the top of the page. The page's [generated source code is here](http://pastebin.com/bgJBZ3k5).

Running the curl command, modified to work on Windows, seemed as if it worked, but it changed nothing on the grey webpage.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"auth_token\": \"YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN\", \"text\": \"Hey, Look what I can do!\" }" http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome
```

The console running the server showed the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2015 11:55:58] "POST /widgets/welcome HTTP/1.1" 204 - 0.0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You must have [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/) or some kind of Javascript engine installed.